# How to plot greyscale values from 300x300 RBG images in python

Tags: python, image, classification, rgb, grayscale

I have a file of 1,500 RBG images with 300x300 dimension that I want to get the greyscale values for in order to plot the greyscale values in a histogram. Once these values are in a histogram I can determine which image have more noise than others. This is for the purpose of image classification exploratory data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. The action you ask is fundamental and you could probably find the answer yourself. A minimal effort is required to get any answer here.

Anyway a quick start could be to use pillow library to read your images:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('path/to/an/image)
image.show()
image2 = image.convert('L')
image2.show()
```

and you probably also need numpy to continue:

```
image_np = np.array(image2)
....
```

then you can do whatever you want with your values. If you have other question you should ask specific question by providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).